# Is there a reverse proxy in Elastic Beanstalk Ruby stack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Ruby application servers aren't very good at dealing with slow clients, are requests and responses from the app deployed with Elastic Beanstalk cached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it defaults to using Nginx as a reverse proxy. You can see this information [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts.platforms.html#concepts.platforms.ruby). You might have to tweak the Nginx settings to enable caching.